# Invalid characters and post-update-cmd error on composer update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

When I try to update any dependencies I get the error below:

```
1 - [ErrorException]                                                             
  Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored

2 - Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Composer file:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "skovmand/mailchimp-laravel": "1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "google/cloud": "^0.135.0",
        "superbalist/flysystem-google-storage": "^7.2",
        "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.16.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the behalf of OP:

> **Run below cmd to fix this:**
>
> ```
> composer update --no-scripts --no-plugins
> ```